# updateTabsetPanel with Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

Having issues calling `updateTabsetPanel` within a Shiny module, works fine without.

```
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("back"), "back")
  )
}

mod <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$back, {
    print("Button click, go back to home tab")
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "home")
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  "example",
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    "home",
    h4("updateTabsetPanel does not work with modules"),
    h5("But the button below does"),
    actionButton("switch", "switch")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "secondtab",
    mod_ui("second")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(mod, "second")
  observeEvent(input$switch, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "secondtab")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modules are designed in such a way that each module is absolutely self contained. If you need to communicate with the parent which called the module, parameters need to be passed explicitly. Here is how it is done:

```
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("back"), "back")
  )
}

mod <- function(input, output, session,parent_session){
  observeEvent(input$back, {
    print("Button click, go back to home tab")
    updateTabsetPanel(session = parent_session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "home")
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  "example",
  id = "tabs",
  tabPanel(
    "home",
    h4("updateTabsetPanel does not work with modules"),
    h5("But the button below does"),
    actionButton("switch", "switch")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "secondtab",
    mod_ui("second")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(mod, "second",parent_session = session)
  observeEvent(input$switch, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "secondtab")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The parent `session` is explicitly passed to the module.