# Dynamic showing/hiding tabPanels in a shiny modal

Tags: shiny, modal-dialog, show-hide, tabpanel

I'm trying to dynamically show/hide tabPanels inside a shiny "modal" in my app but I cant work it out. If I use my current code and simply put the tabPanels inside the main body of the app, the code works just fine so it seems like somehow the app does not recognize that it has to show/hid panels inside the modal.

```
   library(shiny)

   tabPanel_modal<-function() {
     modalDialog(
       tabsetPanel(
         id = "available_tabs",
         tabPanel(
           title = "Tab A",
           value = "tab_a"
         ),
         tabPanel(
           title = "Tab B",
           value = "tab_b"
         ),
         tabPanel(
           title = "Tab C",
           value = "tab_c"
         )
       )
       ,
       size = "l",
       footer = tagList(
         modalButton("Close")
       )
     )
   } 
   ui <- shinyUI(
     fluidPage(
       checkboxGroupInput(
         inputId = "tab_selections",
         label = "select tabs to include in the modal", 
         choiceNames = list("Tab A",
                            "Tab B",
                            "Tab C"
         ),
         choiceValues = c("a","b","c")
       ),
       actionButton("start_modal","Start modal")
     )
   )

   server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

     observeEvent(input$start_modal,{
       showModal(tabPanel_modal())

     })
     observe({
       hideTab(inputId = "available_tabs", target = "tab_a")
       hideTab(inputId = "available_tabs", target = "tab_b")
       hideTab(inputId = "available_tabs", target = "tab_c")
     })
     observeEvent(input$start_modal, {
       if ("a" %in% input$tab_selections){
         showTab(inputId = "available_tabs", target = "tab_a")
       }
       if ("b" %in% input$tab_selections){
         showTab(inputId = "available_tabs", target = "tab_b")
       }
       if ("c" %in% input$tab_selections){
         showTab(inputId = "available_tabs", target = "tab_c")
       }
     })
   })

   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't have a solution but your issue is due to the isolation of modules. You are trying to pass inputs from the main server to a module which is not meant to handle that. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750932/updatetabsetpanel-with-shiny-module) and it seems creating a different `session` could be your answer as you are defining where to do the action (i.e. removing the isolation) but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Looking at some GitHub threads, it looks like the idea is not to do what you are trying to do, [here](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/154) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1891).

Comment: Thanks Kevin, just a quick note. For example, if you define a sliderInput inside the modal, you can use updateSliderInput from your server to change the maximum value of the slider inside the modal using a number you entered inside your main UI. So, this means that modal isolation is not an issue and you're able to communicate to your modal from inside your server. You can basically make any dynamic change inside your modal from your server but you can't somehow access the tabPanel...