# Passing additional parameters to moduleServer in R Shiny app: accessing parent environment for updateTabsetPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

- As of Shiny 1.5.0, [we are encouraged](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) to use `moduleServer` rather than `callModule`.
- However, it appears as though we can't pass additional parameters to `moduleServer` (unlike `callModule`).
- This is an issue because I'd like to pass the parent session as a parameter to `moduleServer`, so that I can correctly reference the parent session in order for `updateTabsetPanel` to work correctly inside a `renderUI` dynamic output.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750932/updatetabsetpanel-with-shiny-module) demonstrates how to use `callModule` to pass the parent session into the module so that `updateTabsetPanel` can reference the parent session and update it accordingly. I used that approach to create a minimal example here. There are two `tabPanel`s, and we are trying to navigate to the second via an `actionLink` in the first. The `first_server` module is called with `callModule`, and we are able to pass the parent session parameter as an additional argument, allowing us to reference it in the `updateTabsetPanel` call in `first_server`. Clicking the `actionLink` then takes us to the second module UI, as expected:

```
library(shiny)

first_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    uiOutput(ns("goto_second_link_ui"))
}

second_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    p("It worked!")
}

first_server <- function(input, output, session, parent) {
    output$goto_second_link_ui <- renderUI({
        actionLink(session$ns("goto_second"), label = "Go to second module")
    })
    observeEvent(input$goto_second, {
        updateTabsetPanel(parent,
            inputId = "main",
            selected = "second"
        )
    })
}

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        tabsetPanel(id = "main",
            tabPanel(value = "first",
                title = "First module",
                first_ui("first")    
            ),
            tabPanel(value = "second",
                title = "Second module",
                second_ui("second")    
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(first_server, id = "first", parent = session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried a couple of approaches to get this to work with `moduleServer`. The best guess I had was to pass the parent session all the way through to the `module` argument of `moduleServer` (relevant changes only shown):

```
first_server <- function(id, parent) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session, parent = parent) {
        output$goto_second_link_ui <- renderUI({
            actionLink(session$ns("goto_second"), label = "Go to second module")
        })
        observeEvent(input$goto_second, {
            updateTabsetPanel(parent,
                inputId = "main",
                selected = "second"
            )
        })
    })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    first_server("first", parent = session)
}
```

This generates an error when I click the `actionLink` that I don't fully understand:

> Warning: Error in updateTabsetPanel: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Thanks for reading and any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you remove the extra argument in `moduleServer` it works.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

first_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("goto_second_link_ui"))
}

second_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  p("It worked!")
}

first_server <- function(id,parent) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    output$goto_second_link_ui <- renderUI({
      actionLink(ns("goto_second"), label = "Go to second module")
    })
    observeEvent(input$goto_second, {
      updateTabsetPanel(parent,
                        inputId = "main",
                        selected = "second"
      )
    })
  })
}

ui <- {
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id = "main",
                tabPanel(value = "first",
                         title = "First module",
                         first_ui("first")    
                ),
                tabPanel(value = "second",
                         title = "Second module",
                         second_ui("second")    
                )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  first_server("first", parent = session)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```