# How to updateTabsetPanel from module?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm trying to make a modular app that can change between modules from the touch of a button using updateTabsetPanel, but I've not been able to communicate with the module. I will attach a simple program that somehow represents what I mean with this

```
library(shiny)
boton_ui = function(id){

ns = NS(id)
actionButton(ns('prueba'),'prueba de cambio')

}

boton_server = function(input,output,session){
  observeEvent(input$prueba,{
    updateTabsetPanel(session,'barra','adios')
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
navbarPage(
    title = "Calculadora de cupos",
    id = "barra",
    tabPanel('Iniciar proceso', 
             boton_ui('boton')),
    tabPanel('Panel de cálculo', 'Adios', value = 'adios')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(boton_server,'boton')

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not reproducible. What is `boton_ui`? Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is in particular self-contained.

Comment: @Jan, just changed, my bad. Now it is reproducible

Comment: Does this answer your question: [updateTabsetPanel with Shiny module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750932/updatetabsetpanel-with-shiny-module)